# Url unicode on php

Tags: php, iis, encoding

We are trying to add non-english chars to the site URL and inside text.

Currently php pages don't see Unicode 'get' arguments. The pages see the arguments as question marks, although we added `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">`

[See sample here.](http://www.free-ringtones.cc/free_mp3_ringtones.php?search=%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A4&sort=search)

Many thanks!

Comment: Are thwe question marks coming from your database? exactly what characters/character-set are you trying to render? also, you can't have a URL that's non-ascii. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504564/can-http-uris-have-non-ascii-characters

Answer (score 1):

Output the strings trough `utf8_encode()`;