# Ugly utf-8 characters in URL?

Tags: angular, urlencode

I am working on a French website where I need to use utf-8 characters. Angular 2 is showing

```
http://localhost:4200/#/portefeuille/%C3%A9tude
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:4200/#/portefeuille/étude
```

Any solution to solve this issue?

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504564/can-http-uris-have-non-ascii-characters. You can't have non-ASCII characters in URIs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what about this http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/étude/31591